# Binomial Expansion coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Find the coefficient of $x^3 y^4$ in the expansion of $(2x-4y)^7$. I would also like an explanation for how the final answer was obtained.

Comment: Binomial expansion
\begin{eqnarray*}
(2x-4y)^7= \cdots +\binom{7}{3}(2x)^3 (-4y)^4 +\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: How did you choose that combination and what would the final answer be?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
(a+b)^n= \cdots +\binom{n}{r}a^r b^{n-r} +\cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
What term do you need to choose to obtain the monomial $x^3 y^4$ ? ... simplify ? You tell me what you think. $\ddot \smile$

Comment: n=7 and r would have to equal 3. I just don't understand how this summation (if it is a summation) works

Comment: I do understand how you assigned values to r and n the question now is just how the recipe works

Comment: Try expanding $(a+b)^2$ and $(a+b)^3$ ... look carefully at the terms ... now have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 0):

The Binomial Theorem states 
$$(a+b)^n= \sum_{r=0}^{n}\binom{n}{ r} (a)^{n-r}(b)^r$$
and so
$$(2x-4y)^7=\sum_{r=0}^{7}\binom{7}{ r} (2x)^{7-r}(-4y)^r.$$

So, we simply need to consider the $5$th term  (i.e., when $r=4$):
$$\binom{7}{ 4} (2x)^{7-4}(-4y)^4=\binom{7}{4}2^34^4x^3y^4.$$

I’ll leave it to you to evaluate what this equals.

In general, whenever you are asked to find a particular coefficient in the Binomial expansion, try to reword the question into one which asks “What value of $r$ will give me the desired term?” and then evaluate $$\binom{n}{r}(a)^{n-r}(b)^{r}$$ for that particular $r$, as I did above.

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^3y^4]}&\color{blue}{(2x-4y)^7}\\
> &=[x^3y^4]\sum_{k=0}^7\binom{7}{k}(2x)^k(-4y)^{7-k}\tag{1}\\
> &=[y^4]\binom{7}{3}2^3(-4y)^4\tag{2}\\
> &=\binom{7}{3}2^3(-4)^4\tag{3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=71\,680}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (2) we select the coefficient of $x^3$.
- In (3) we select the coefficient of $x^4$.